# jupyter lab kernel dies when trying to run hvplot

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, python-xarray, holoviews, hvplot

when trying to run the following code, the jupyter lab kernel dies with no error output, something to do with hvplot but after several hour of searching, I am unable to find anything regarding this matter:

```
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf
from cartopy import crs
import hvplot.pandas

import geopandas as gpd
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

cities.hvplot(global_extent=True, frame_height=450, tiles=True)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?